# How to do the action only once on two events?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mouseevent, stylus

I'm on a C# WPF application, I have a HOME button, on this button I currently have a `StylusButtonDown` event with actions in front. I want to have a second `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event on this same button but not have to write the actions twice.
It is possible to write a method and then call this method in both actions but it is not optimal.
Is it possible to create a button that when pressing `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`, does exactly as pressing the `StylusButtonDown`?

Here's what I don't want to do:

```
private void BP_31N00_StylusButtonUp(object sender, StylusButtonEventArgs e)
{
   ModifyManualVelocityApparence(ref BP_31N00, true);
   ModifyManualVelocityApparence(ref BP_31N01, fallse);
   ModifyManualVelocityApparence(ref BP_32N04, false);
   ModifyManualVelocityApparence(ref BP_32N05, false);
   ModifyManualVelocityApparence(ref BP_32N06, false);
   ModifyManualVelocityApparence(ref BP_84J01, false);
   ModifyManualVelocityApparence(ref BP_86J01, false);
   ModifyManualVelocityApparence(ref BP_87J01, false);
   ModifyManualVelocityApparence(ref BP_EtherCATNetwork, false);

   FRM_ParameterChannel.Content = page31N00;
   actualPage = 0;
}
private void BP_31N00_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   ModifyManualVelocityApparence(ref BP_31N00, true);
   ModifyManualVelocityApparence(ref BP_31N01, fallse);
   ModifyManualVelocityApparence(ref BP_32N04, false);
   ModifyManualVelocityApparence(ref BP_32N05, false);
   ModifyManualVelocityApparence(ref BP_32N06, false);
   ModifyManualVelocityApparence(ref BP_84J01, false);
   ModifyManualVelocityApparence(ref BP_86J01, false);
   ModifyManualVelocityApparence(ref BP_87J01, false);
   ModifyManualVelocityApparence(ref BP_EtherCATNetwork, false);

   FRM_ParameterChannel.Content = page31N00;
   actualPage = 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code to your question as text? Don't add code as images - its harder to read and we can't copy/paste to replicate problem, if needed.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. Is it only about not duplicating the code?

Answer (score 0):

Since the code is exactly the same and it seems like you don't have to access external attributes you can just connect 2 buttons with the same onClick Method, just go select the button -> properties -> onClick -> and then select the same onClick method from the dropDown menu in the 2 buttons